# How can we use custom RBAC in yii2

Tags: php, yii2, rbac

Is it possible to try RBAC tutorials in this link in yii2

http://www.sitepoint.com/role-based-access-control-in-php/

i dont know how to try this in yii2

someone please help me or suggest any custom methods like this can be implemented in yii2

Comment: You should be able to find anything you need here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html

Maybe that will help clarify some stuff because you question is way too general to be answered easily.

Comment: i want to use RBAC DbManager and also i migrated it ..but dont know what to do next.
1)Do i create CRUD for add/edit entries to those imported tables?
2)what other customization i need to apply in controller(anything on behavior ...etc)?

Answer (score 0):

Yii have posted their own now, check this here:

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html